# ¿Por qué hay diferencias entre los tipos de eventos que escucha un componente?

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

He estado curioseando con los componentes gráficos de `Swing` en `Java` usando NetBeans 8.2 en Windows 10 y me encontré un comportamiento que no he podido explicarme. Lo expongo a continuación:

Si se da doble clic sobre un componente gráfico, automáticamente crea un método `ActionPerformed` que se ejecutará cada vez que se detecte un evento para ese componente. Para probar simplemente puse una salida de sistema:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here
    System.out.println("Botón")
}
```

Y lo mismo hice con un `TextField`, doble clic para crear el método `ActionPerformed` y puse una salidad de sistema:

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("TextField");
}
```

Lo único que agregué fueron los métodos de `ActionPerformed`, todas las demás propiedades de cada elemento las dejé como están predefinidas. Sin embargo, cada componente actua de manera diferente de acuerdo a la acción que realizo sobre cada uno:

- Botón:

  - Presionar la tecla "Enter": no muestra la salida de consola.
  - Hacer clic: muestra la salida de consola.
  - Presionar la barra espaciadora: muestra salida de consola.
- Text Field:

  - Presionar la tecla "Enter": muestra salida de consola.
  - Hacer clic: no muestra la salida de consola.
  - Presionar la barra espaciadora: no muestra salida de consola.

Pensé que quitando la propiedad de Editable al `TextField` ya tomaría el espacio y el clic como eventos, pero siguió mostrando el mismo comportamiento.

Estuve investigando un poco acerca de los eventos, pero la mayor parte de lo que encontré fueron ejemplos de código para implementar un `Listener`, por lo que "me quedé en las mismas".

¿Alguna idea de por qué se comportan diferente?
¿Qué es lo que hace que un componente ejecute (o no) la acción si se le aplican los mismos eventos que al otro?

Gracias de antemano :)

**Actualización mar09-jul-2019:** por casualidad me di cuenta que en Linux (concretamente en Ubuntu y Debian, no he probado en otras distribuciones), al presionar la tecla Enter cuando el focus está sobre el botón, **si** muestra la salida de sistema, cosa que no hace en Windows. Al parecer el evento de presionar la tecla Enter se interpreta diferente en Windows y Linux.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "Y lo mismo hice con un `TextField`"? ¿Se generó código para algún evento del textfield o no? Con esto, podría darte una posible respuesta.

Comment: Me refiero a que di clic dos veces sobre él para generar el método de `jTextField1ActionPerformed` y dentro puse una salida a consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que se comporten de manera diferente ante un evento, sino que el evento se lanza en diferentes situaciones para cada componente.

Un `JTextField` es un campo de texto, y debe comportarse como tal.
Es de esperar que cuando estás rellenando un campo, puedas pulsar el espacio y sea tomado como parte de la información que estás ingresando en el campo de texto.

Así mismo, cuando haces *click*, el campo de texto no debería hacer nada más que obtener el foco, es decir, situar el cursor en el campo para poder rellenarlo.

En casi todos los formularios, al pulsar ENTER se suele llevar a cabo una acción: validar el campo, hacer una llamada como si pulsaras el botón de aceptar del formulario, etc.

Así, los diseñadores de `swing` decidieron que un `JTextField` se iba a comportar como tal. Es decir, cuando haces *click* sobre el campo se lanza un`FocusEvent`, para poder hacer algo al ganar el foco. Y cuando pulsas ENTER se lanza un `ActionEvent`, pues se espera que la pulsación de la tecla lleve a alguna acción.

Cuando pulsas un espacio, me parece que se lanza un `KeyEvent`, por si quieres capturar las pulsaciones de las teclas para, por ejemplo, ir validando un campo mientras el usuario lo va rellenando.

Un `JButton` en cambio, no es un campo que vayas a rellenar, por lo que lanzará eventos en situaciones diferentes a los de un campo de texto.

Para empezar, un botón no suele reaccionar ante algunas teclas, sino ante el *click*, que para eso son botones y no elementos donde escribir.

De nuevo, los diseñadores decidieron (porque era lo normal o lo más lógico para ellos), que un `JButton` lanzaría un `ActionEvent` al pulsar espacio o hacer *click* en el botón.

Pero, ¿por qué no reacciona (lanza el evento) ante la tecla ENTER?

Para mí resulta lógico que se lance un `ActionEvent` al pulsar la tecla ENTER en un botón, pero al parecer para los diseñadores no. Creo que esto es porque se necesita que el botón gane el foco para pulsar ENTER sobre el botón, y no siempre los botones son `focusables`. De hecho, por defecto (dependiendo del sistema y de la `FocusTraversalPolicy` del contenedor) los botones suelen ser elementos que no ganan el foco.

En este caso, puede tener sentido que no lancen `ActionEvent` por defecto al pulsar ENTER. Pero lo puedes simular, ya que sí que se lanzará un `KeyEvent`, que se puede capturar y ejecutar el código del `ActionEvent` allí también.

En conclusión, los componentes no se comportan de maneras diferentes ante un mismo evento (en este caso), sino que los propios eventos son lanzados en diferentes situaciones, como es el caso de pulsar ENTER, que en un `JTextField` lleva a lanzar un `ActionEvent`, mientras que en un `JButton` lleva a lanzar un `KeyEvent`.

En realidad, además, una misma situación puede llevar a lanzar varios eventos y no solo uno.

Pulsar la tecla ENTER puede llevar a lanzar tanto un `KeyEvent`, como un `ActionEvent`, dependiendo del componente (campo de texto en este caso), por lo que es decisión tuya cual evento vas a capturar.

Otro ejemplo sería hacer *click* sobre un botón, que podría lanzar un `ActionEvent` y **varios** `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Vaya respuesta, me quedó claro t-o-d-o, ahora entiendo muchas cosas. Sobre lo que mencionas "... los componentes no se comportan de maneras diferentes ante un mismo evento (en este caso), sino que los propios eventos son lanzados en diferentes situaciones..."

¿podría ser algo relacionado con el sistema operativo? Actualicé mi pregunta haciendo referencia a que hay un comportamiento diferente en Windows y Linux.

Comment: Efectivamente, aparte de que ante una misma situación se lanzan eventos distintos, según el sistema que uses, la entrada puede ser procesada de manera diferente. Windows, por ejemplo, tiene su propio sistema de eventos de teclado, diferente al de Linux. El sistema puede capturar algunas pulsaciones y consumirlas, o bien interpretarlas de manera distinta cada sistema, pasando eventos distintos a la JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Entonces, el botón se comporta como tal, al presionarlo ejecutará el código que pusiste al interno de la `ActionPerformed`, para que funcione la tecla enter tendrías que poner un `TextField` y agregarle un `listener` que podría ser algo así :

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
     SubmitButton listener = new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterName);
     textBoxToEnterName.addActionListener(listener);
     submit.addKeyListener(listener);
   }
 }
```

Mientras que el `TextField` simplemente sirve para captar o mostrar un texto, aunque hagas click el no va a hacer absolutamente nada siendo un simple campo de texto, cuando le sacas la propiedad de editable lo único que le afecta es el hecho de que no puedes editar el contenido (salvo que lo hagas del lado código, ejem : `textField1.setText("hola mundo")` al interno de la `action` de un botón).

Espero que la explicación te haya aclarado un poco las dudas, saludos.